# Pretty new to Python, how to write code for this test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, typeerror

i'm pretty new to python, and my instructor has a series of unit tests that we had to write code for. I've gotten all of them pretty easy, except for this:

```
class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_failure(self):
        l = ListClass()
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as typ:
            l.sortlist("string")
            exc = typ.exception
            self.assertEqual(exc.error_code, "Input isn't a list")
```

i've tried many ways to get this to return a successful test, but I can't figure it out. currently my code (which has gone through a ton of changes and probably doesn't make much sense) looks like this:

```
class ListClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    class TypeError(Exception):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def sortlist(num_list):
        try:
            inst = isinstance(num_list, list)
            if inst:
                num_list.sort()
                return num_list
            else:
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            print("Input isn't a list")
```

The error I consistently get while fiddling with my code is:

```
ERROR: test_failure (__main__.Tester)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ---------, line 13, in test_failure
    exc = typ.exception
AttributeError: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i'm trying to figure out what this error means. is the '_AssertRaisesContext' object part of a python library?

Comment: Why is `sortlist` catching its own exception? That defeats the point of raising it.

Comment: Also, `TypeError` is built-in. You're not supposed to define your own version.

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Thank you. I tried containing everything in the function because of how the unit test was structured, but turns out I didn't need to do that.